# Can't get out this while loop

Tags: python-3.x

I want this loop to break when user enters anything but y or Y. But, instead the **Enter the new location** prompt is returning again and again.

```
    def add_locations(self):
        while True:
            new = str(input("Enter the new loation: "))
            self.locations.append(new)
            ask = str(input("add new location? (y/n):  "))
            if ask == 'y' or 'Y':
                continue
            else:
                break
```

[image]

Comment: BTW your `str()` conversion is not necessary as `input()` already returns a string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your if-clause is evaluated like this: `(ask == 'y') or 'Y'` and 'Y' is always true. You need to ask `if ask == 'y' or ask == 'Y':` instead

Comment: It's a good practice to use parentheses: `if (ask == 'y') or (ask == 'Y')`

Comment: Or a better practice to do `if ask in ('y', 'Y')` or in this particular case: `if ask.lower() == 'y'`

Comment: @Tomerikoo yes! you're definitely right!

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can put all your positive values into a `tuple`:

```py
while True:
    new = str(input("Enter the new location: "))
    self.locations.append(new)
    ask = str(input("add new location? (y/n):  "))
    if ask.lower() in ('y', 'yes'):
        continue
    else:
        break
```

Comment: Yes, that's a good alternative. Thanks.